# Ajax returning all database records instead of queried results

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, slim

I am working on a search box in PHP that will get results from a database. Since I want the search to be live, I'm using an Ajax script to get the results.

This is the javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $('#search').keyup(function() {
    var txt = $(this).val();
    if (txt != '' && txt.length >= 6) {
      $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '{{ path_for('search.post') }}',
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);// Do stuff with data.
        }
      });
    } else {
      $('#search_results').html('');
    }
  });
});
```

path_for('search.post') calls a PHP function (using Slim 3). This function is:

```
$queryString = "SELECT displayName
                     FROM guests
                     INNER JOIN shows ON guests.showId = shows.showId
                     WHERE (displayName LIKE :search OR talk_title LIKE :search) AND shows.active = 1 AND guests.active = 1
                     ORDER BY gLastName";

$searchQuery = $this->c->db->prepare($queryString);
$searchText = '%'.$request->getParam('search').'%';
$searchQuery->bindValue(':search', $searchText, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$searchQuery->execute();

$results = $searchQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$jsonResults = json_encode($results);

echo $jsonResults;
```

If I run the PHP directly, I get a json string with the record(s) I searched for (usually one or two depending on what I search). However, if I let the Ajax run, I get back every single record in the database. I don't understand why this is.

If have tested that the ajax is calling the right PHP by changing to echo 'yes'. When I did this, I received the string 'yes' back.

Is there something I need to change in the Ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

I just realised what the error is. 
$request->getParam('search') only works when I run the PHP directly, but not with Ajax since the parameter is not being posted.

Once I changed the ajax call to this:

```
$.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '{{ path_for('search.post') }}',
        data: {search:txt},
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);// Do stuff with data.
        }
      });
```

it worked.